# Что такое А. А?

Tags: словообразование

Лингвисты назвали «а?» универсальным СЛОВОМ. В исследовании ученые рассматривали выборку из 10 языков, в том числе входящих в разные семьи: русский, итальянский, испанский, китайский, исландский, лаосский, голландский, эквадорский ча-палаа, австралийский язык Муррин-пата и язык сиву, на котором говорят в Гане. 
Лингвисты анализировали записи повседневных разговоров и выделяли из них только те случаи употребления междометия, когда собеседник выражал просьбу повторить то, что он не расслышал (во многих языках «а» употребляется и в других значениях, но их ученые не рассматривали). Фрагменты записей демонстрировали для фонетического анализа трем независимым лингвистам «вслепую»: они не знали, какому языку принадлежит тот или иной кусок. Во второй части работы проводили компьютерное сравнение испанской «а?» и того же междометия из языка ча-палаа. 
Ученые выяснили, что, во-первых, «а?» является настоящим СЛОВОМ, а не биологическим звуком. Междометие встроено в лингвистическую систему носителя и изменяется от одного языка к другому: например, дополняется придыханием, если это характерно для языка. Во-вторых, оно оказалось очень фонетически похоже в самых разных языках. В-третьих, междометие не является врожденным и требует обучения — дети научаются правильно его употреблять только к пяти годам. В-четвертых, «а?» из-за краткости не всегда можно заменить другим словом, вроде «что?», поэтому оно имеет большое значение в устной речи. Из этого ученые делают вывод о том, что междометие стало универсальным словом в результате конвергентной эволюции, то есть приобрело сходный вид из-за сходной функции.

Comment: Ни комментарий, ни вопрос. Но тема живая. Можно ещё о "М" поговорить, о "Ш", о "Ё". К примеру, «а?» из-за краткости не всегда можно заменить другим словом, вроде «что?", а "М?" можно, и более того экономно, - не открывая рта.

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит правдоподобным. Например, для основного диалекта китайского, где такая частица в разных тонах имеет разный смысл (подтверждение, восклицание, обращение), именно во втором тоне (похожем на "a?") по смыслу имеет место переспрашивание. Но для строгости выводов придётся учёным порыться и в остальных диалектах (в Китае 56 национальностей со своими гербами и диалектами, в которых до 9 тонов), иначе это останется просто красивой гипотезой. Пусть начнут с простого: с кантонского (всего 6 тонов) и шанхайского диалектов, которые от основного языка отличаются на 80 и 60 процентов соответственно и поищут там тона слога "а", похожие на испанский вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Простите, но более всего напоминает пересказ какой-то бессмыслицы от "британских ученых".

Что именно исследуется, каким методом, каковы конкретные результаты?

> во-первых, «а?» является настоящим СЛОВОМ, а не биологическим звуком.

Допустим, хотя аргументация - ниже всякой критики. А что это дает?

И самое главное, а причем тут универсальность?

> Междометие встроено в лингвистическую систему носителя и изменяется от одного языка к другому:

Я думаю, если представителям популяций ишаков из разных регионов всего ареала их обитания заталкивать под хвост тряпку со скипидаром, то набор издаваемых ими звуков будет несравнимо разнообразнее.